Skoda Octavia 2014 Coolant Leak?
Coolant warning light came on and the level was below minimum. Topped it up. I can't see an obvious leak but it is going down slowly.
Local garage pointed at some pink speckled on the right of the engine bay (pictured) and quoted £450 for a water pump.
Does this seem legit?


It's hard to tell from the picture, but the pink spots usually does mean some kind of coolant leak if your coolant is pink or red to start with ... Who knows if it's the water pump, though.
